# How to install the Hokuyo URG-04LX laser-ranger driver?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I'm a newer to ROS . Anyway i tried to create a map with laser scanner, Hokuyo URG-04LX.But I really dont know how to install the drivers of it.

Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233845/how-to-install-the-hokuyo-urg-04lx--laser-ranger-driver?/) by [Aimule](https://answers.ros.org/users/26795/aimule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

There are two ros packages that can work with this device, both of them work well and they are also well documented.

This one works only for the usb based laser-scanners

http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node

An this other works for both usb and ethernet based drivers

http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node

Regards,

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2016-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aimule](https://answers.ros.org/users/26795/aimule/) on 2016-05-09**:
Thanks, I have installed the driver of it.